# MongoDB + PHP: How to push item to array with a spcecific key?

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

In MongoDB-PHP I am using the following example code to push a new entry to the end of an array inside a collection...

```
$data = array(
        "domain"=>"superduperyoyo.com",
        "number"=>123,
        "week"=>5,
        "year"=>2012
);
$db->domains->save(
        array( 'someid' => $someid),
        array( '$push' => array( 'data' => $data ))
);
```

This returns keys like 0,1,2,3....
ie.

```
[someid] => somesupercoolid123
[data] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [domain] => superduperyoyo.com
                [number] => 123
                [week] => 5
                [year] => 2012
            )
        [1] => Array(...)
        [2] => Array(...)
    )
```

What I want to do is store YearWeekNumber as the key like this...

```
 [someid] => somesupercoolid123 
   [data] => Array
        (
            [201205123] => Array
                (
                    [domain] => superduperyoyo.com
                    [number] => 123
                    [week] => 5
                    [year] => 2012
                )
            [201206123] => Array(...)
            [201207123] => Array(...)
        )
```

How do you save/update the key along with the new entry? I am assuming you can't use $push. That you just use .save or .update but how do you pass the key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd do this by using `$set`:

```
$data = array(
        "domain"=>"superduperyoyo.com",
        "number"=>123,
        "week"=>5,
        "year"=>2012
);
$db->domains->update(
        array( 'someid' => $someid),
        array( '$set' => array( 'data' => array( 201205123 => $data )))
);
```

I would however not recommend doing this. It's better to set another key with this "201205123" value as otherwise you wouldn't be able to do range queries on this value or set an index.

Comment: I just started dabling with Mongo and am trying out different schemas. I would index "number","week","year"... the key is just for pulling out an individual record explicitly if needed and also so I dont have duplicates. Set/Save will update instead of Insert it again.

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = array(
        "domain"=>"superduperyoyo.com",
        "number"=>123,
        "week"=>5,
        "year"=>2012
);
```

```php
 $update = array(
        '$push' => array('data.201205123'  =>  $data )
);
```